# Action bar is showing when using NoActionBar theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-styles

I am using a theme with NoActionBar. Manifest file:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"
```

I am using another Action bar, which I include to the layout:

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

However, I always get two Toolbars, and the upper one is the one, which would be there if I did not use NoActionBar theme. I found out, that if I delete this part in styles.xml file, it works as it should - there is no second action bar:

```
<style name="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

Of course I would like to keep this in the style.xml file as this helps to set up also the colour of the notification panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me this fails because `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` is an existant theme and you are creating it in the styles.xml so it overrides the existant one.

What I do is to create a new theme setting the one I want to edit as the `parent` theme:

```
<style name="AppNoActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

And then set this new theme on the manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/AppNoActionBar"
```

This way you'll have the properties of the base theme (`Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`) with the custom updates.